# 2D arrays processing

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, array-algorithms

I have a 2d array which has either a 0 or 1 contained within, i want to write a program that checks to see if there a two 1 lying on the same row or column. It should be a O(n**2) algorithm.
I have written in python a for loop which loops through the array but i don't get how i can check to see if two 1 are contained in either the row or column, maybe someone can give me some tips.
Thanks in advance

```
a = [[1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1]]

for i in range(len(a)) :  
    for j in range(len(a[i])) :  

          print(a[i][j], end=" ")


    print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def two_adjacent_ones(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
        for j in range(len(arr[i]) - 1):
            if (arr[i][j] == 1 and arr[i][j + 1] == 1) or (arr[i][j] == 1 and arr[i + 1][j] == 1):
                return True

    last_row = arr[len(arr) - 1]
    for i in range(len(last_row) - 1):
        if last_row[i] == last_row[i + 1] and last_row[i] == 1:
            return True

    last_column = [arr[i][-1] for i in range(len(arr) - 1)]
    for i in range(len(last_column) - 1):
        if last_column[i] == last_column[i + 1] and last_column[i] == 1:
            return True

    return False

b = [[1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0]]

print(two_adjacent_ones(b))
```

this is the most iterative and not pythonic solution i came up with right now.

Answer (score 0):

This simple code will give you total count of 1s in each row and column

```
a = [[1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1]]
counters_rows = [0, 0]
counters_cols = [0, 0, 0, 0]

for i in range(len(a)) :  
    for j in range(len(a[i])) :  
          if a[i][j] == 1:
            counters_rows[i]+=1
            counters_cols[j]+=1

print('rows: ')
for i in range(len(counters_rows)):
  print(counters_rows[i])

print('columns: ')
for i in range(len(counters_cols)):
  print(counters_cols[i])
```